# Decomposition of $W^{1,p}(a,b)$ = $W^{1,p}_0(a,b) \oplus E$ where $E$ are affine functions

Tags: functional-analysis, sobolev-spaces

First of all, I have to prove that for any function $u \in$  $W^{1,p}(a,b)$  there is a unique affine function $ v \in E = \{Ax+B; A,B \in \mathbb{R} \} $   with the same border conditions $ u(a)=v(a) $ and $ u(b)=v(b) $. Which I have solved making a system and seeing that it has only  one solution.
Then I have to deduce that $W^{1,p}(a,b)$ as direct sum of $ W^{1,p}_0(a,b) \oplus E$ where $E$ are affine functions, and get the respective projections, but I don't really know how to assure that any function can be expressed as a sum of such subspaces .

Thank you in advance .

Comment: Is the decomposition $W^{1,p}(a,b)$ = $W^{1,p}_0(a,b) \oplus E$  is true? To me,  if $a,b < \infty$,  $Ax+B  \in W^{1,p}_0(a,b) $  because the affine function is smooth and its derivatives have finite $L^p$ norms for all $p$. Or you assume that $a$ or $b$ is $\infty$?

Comment: But do not verify the border conditions , right?  I suppose it is true,it is an exercise that I have been proposed by my teachers.

Comment: I guess that $v$ is not an affine, but it is equivalent element with the affine function in $W^{k,p}$. What is $u$?

Comment: the function in $W^{1,p}(a,b)$

Comment: I am not sure the boundary conditions. Because, $L^p$ norm dose not change when we change the value of a function for finite points. More precisely, any element of the $L^p$ space is not a function but, an equivalence class of functions $f,g$ such that $\|f-g\|_{W^{k,p}}=0$. I am wrong?

Comment: I think this is correct

Comment: Do you know the definition of $W^{1,p}_0$

Comment: Yes , the Sobolev functions  $u$ s.t. $u(a)=0$ and $u(b)=0$

Comment: For all $u\in W^{1, p}(a, b)$, let $v$ be the affine function you found, which is unique. Then $u = u-v  + v \in W^{1,p}_0(a, b) \oplus E$.

Comment: The answer is already shown in the comment of @Artic Char

Let $u \in W^{1,p}(a,b)$, then by the Sobolev embedding theorem, $u$ is continuous. Thus, 
The values $u(a),u(b)$ make sense. 
Let $v$ be an affine function satisying the boundary conditions $v(a)=u(a)$ and $v(b)=u(b)$.
Then the function $u-v$ vanishes at boundary of $(a,b)$. Thus we can regard $u-v$ as a contiuous function of $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Using Friedrich's mollfier, any continuous function on $(a,b)$ there is a sequence of smooth functions such that it converges to $u-v$  uniformly on any compact set of $(a,b)$ The difficulty is that the support of this sequence is not contained in $(a,b)$.

Comment: If the support of the convolution of $u$ and mollfier is contained in the support of $u$, then, the sequece of this convolutions is desired one. But,  this Inclusive relationship
is not true. Thus, it make the problem to be difficult. Or, I misunderstand?

Comment: Note that the boundary conditions of $v$ is not correct. It should be $v(a)=u(a)$ and $v(b)=u(b)$. So this condition let $u-v$ be zero on the bourdary of $(a,b)$.